# Simple image filters

Tags: javascript, image, image-processing, imagefilter

What are the **simple Image filters** that can be made from pixel manipulation apart from grayscale and brightness adjustments?
I **don't want convolution filters**, I just want to know about filters that work with one pixel and **not** a group of pixels

Comment: not much. hue, saturation and other intra-pixel adjustments only.

Comment: Hue means  increasing decreasing rgb values? And how do we change saturarion values algorithmically  (without converting to hsv)? What are intra-pixel adjustments?

Comment: saturation is defined as the sub-pixel contrast, so you would exaggerate the difference between the colors, ex: (100,150,100) into (75,175,75). hue adjustment means keeping roughly the over all sum of the sub-pixel values, but re-distributing them. it's easier to adjust hue in hsl, but not impossible with rgb. intra pixel transforms happen without consideration of neighboring pixels; compare to blur, sharpen, resizing, contrast, and the like: they need to consider more than one pixel, and the values of adjacent pixels affect each-others post-transform result value.

Comment: Thank you that helped:)  what are 'other' intra-pixel adjustments that you said, is what I meant to ask. can you reference any material which shows how to  adjust hue and saturation with rgb?